# How can I take a medial triangle as the new frame of reference?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry

We have a reference triangle $ABC$. In the plane of $ABC$, a point $M$ can be written $M=x.A+y.B+z.C$.

But I would like to take the medial triangle $A'B'C'$ of $ABC$ as the new reference triangle.
Do you know how I can find the transformation formulas that give the matrix change frame of reference ?
In other word, how can I express $M=x.A+y.B+z.C$ in terms of $A',B',C'$ ?

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that
$$A'=\frac{A+B}{2},\ B'=\frac{B+C}{2},\ C'=\frac{A+C}{2}.$$
This gives
$$A=A'-B'+C',$$
$$B=B'-C'+A',$$
$$C=B'+C'-A'.$$
Then,
\begin{align}
M&=xA+yB+zC\\
&=x(A'-B'+C')+y(B'-C'+A')+z(B'+C'-A')\\
&=(x+y-z)A'+(y-x+z)B'+(x-y+z)C'.
\end{align}

Comment: I see ! Thank you very much DiegoMath !

Comment: so we have the transformation formulas$$\begin{cases}
x'=-x+y+z\\
y'=x-y+z\\ z'=x+y-z
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @beginarray Yes!